# NuGet Push task, enter a variable name in Target Feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my Azure DevOps CD pipeline, a NuGet package gets pushed to my feed. I am using NuGet task version `2.*`.

When I choose `Push` as the command type, I am trying to enter the variable `$(DevFeed)` (defined in my Variable Group) in the **Target Feed**, however the drop-down is not accepting variable names.

Is there a workaround? Or should I resort to the old task version `1.*`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the tasks are open sources and exist on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks).

If you look the task source code you can see a different between version 1 to version 2.

In [Version 1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/NuGetRestoreV1/task.json) you can find this on the feed picklist field:

```
"properties": {
    "EditableOptions: "True"
}
```

This property give the ability to enter another value that not in the list.

In [Version 2](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/NuGetCommandV2/task.json) of the task is not exist, this is the reason you can't put a variable.

So, it look like you have to use version 1 if you need to use a variable.

Comment: Just as expected, seems I need to use version 1 unless Microsoft adds a newer version with enabled drop down.

Comment: @naregkar Or, you can take the task source code, add this feature and upload as a private extension.